# How to answer on question about hobby which is not something I like?

Tags: relationships

My girlfriend runs an Instagram fashion profile. She shares photos of her and her clothing sets. She asked recently:

> Do you enjoy photographing me? What do you think about this?

And here's the  problem. What I think about fashion at all is that firstly I do not quite understand it (it's not that I don't pay attention to my look), secondly I think it is somehow not necessary (whole this thing about expressing your status with clothes, judging by apperances annoys me). I think clothing should be neat and apropriate to situation. I do not like to pose and when others do this, they seem somehow falsely to me. I do not like all this specifically fashion-blogs, they seem blank to me.

I do tolerate fashion as a hobby. I do want to support my girlfriend in her passion. Photographing her with her phone (which we usually do) is not something I really enjoy, but when she borrows better camera from her friend I do like to play with it (but rather in terms of device, catching lights etc.). I do this because she enjoys that.

What I answered last time was something like:

> Fashion is not for me, I do not quite understand it. When you give me a better camera I enjoy photographing you, but still fashion seems a little blank to me.

How should I answer, so that I do not somehow offend her, still expressing my thoughts but show her support even though I do not quite like it (again I do tolerate it)?

Comment: What was wrong with the response you wrote here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a phrasing request.

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar discussions with my partner. They're something of a fashionista and I prefer cargo shorts, combat boots, and old band t-shirts... I try to play along, and I make an effort to dress up when necessary, but I really don't get fashion at all.

Even though we have very different tastes and place very different values on the importance of that stuff, we still get along and even enjoy going shopping for clothes together.

What seems to make all the difference is remembering to bring a sense of humor and treating the thing with some whimsy. One of our recent dates was going out for silly sunglasses. We deliberately picked out astonishingly gawdy obnoxious sunglasses for each other to try on, full on Elton John styles. We'd model them for each other and then crack jokes about how awful they were or threaten to actually purchase and wear them. Just an example, but even if you loathe fashion you can still have fun with it.

As far as your specific situation, you could just be honest. Tell her that fashion doesn't really do much for you, but you find the photography somewhat interesting. Framing it in a positive light will probably help. Something like:

> Fashion doesn't really do much for me, but I enjoy photography, and it's always nice to spend time with you.

Sharing hobbies in a relationship is nice, but it isn't mandatory. In your case it sounds like you two may have somewhat complementary interests. Fashion and photography go hand in hand pretty well. If you need a better camera rig to keep it interesting for you consider picking up a few pieces of used camera equipment. Be warned photography isn't a cheap hobby.

If you really can't stand the fashion focus, (so punny) you could be honest about that too. Just be gentle about it. One of my exes was an aspiring model, and while I wasn't really interested enough to participate in her hobby with her, I made an effort to be encouraging and supportive. When she'd strike a pose I'd tell her she was stunning, but I left the camera work to a friend of hers.

> You look absolutely beautiful, but let's let Alice handle the photos, she's much better at it than I am anyway.

If you can, try to have fun with it. If it's not fun for you, don't spoil the fun for them.